# Is there a utility that lets you limit the number of windows that can be UNminimized at a time?

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to make it so only the last 2-3 windows that I touched remain open, as soon as I open a 3rd/4th window it should minimize the 1st one, and so forth.

This it to help keep clutter and distraction off of my desktop.

Would be even better if I could somehow keep them out of the taskbar or put them all into one taskbar item regardless of type when they are hidden...

Please don't recommend using a Spaces clone for multidesktop because that does not help me either, then I just end up with desktop after desktop full of windows.

I need a way for this to happen automatically so I can just keep working quickly switching from one thing to another.

Would be cool if it could even shut down programs that I allow it to shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TaskTop](http://www.tasktop.com/). It may or may not do exactly like you wanted. But since you want to solve your management problem(s), this may help.

> Tasktop Pro is the supported,
>   enterprise-ready product built on
>   Eclipse Mylyn with additional
>   productivity features and connectors.
>   Tasktop Pro extends task focus to your
>   time tracking, web browsing, desktop
>   documents and includes connectors to 
>   Mingle, ScrumWorks Pro , Firefox,
>   Google Apps, Outlook, and more.

- Commercial. Free trial available.

Answer (score 0):

I found [MinimOther](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/#MinimOther) which partly does what you want. It automatically minimises all but the current window. I've not used it, but as it's written with autohotkey it may be customisable to 3 windows?

Answer (score -1):

The only that's built-in in Windows 7 is Aero Shake.

Just shake your current window and all other windows get minimized.

It's the closest you can do without an additional tool.

Comment: It only keeps 1 window "un-minimized", not 2 or 3 as requested.